# How can I control the connection/disconnection of 8 bi-directional logic level lines, one 5V-50mA power, and a ground line with one SPST switch?

Tags: integrated-circuit

Using a single SPST switch, is there an IC (or other device) that can act as a relay for 10 individual circuits?  8 Logic level bi-directional lines, one 5V-50mA power, and one ground.

I considered using 10 transistors, but I don't believe the bi-directional logic data would work over this.

Comment: new2arduino - Please edit the question and add more details about (a) these "serial data lines"; (b) the two systems which they are linking and (c) your reason for needing to switch them. For example: You say they are 5V (that might imply normal logic signals), but then you say 50mA max (which does *not* suggest normal logic signals). In case you are using some kind of maximum pin specification to give that 50mA specification, when in fact that current is not needed, it would help readers to "sanity check" the specification for you to add those details about these signals & devices. Thanks.

Comment: @new2arduino are you connecting/disconnecting 10 data sources from 10 data sinks?  Or 10 data sources from1 master, ie multiplexing?  10 sources to 10 sinks randomly, ie. crosspoint switch?  I think you should draw a schematic of how you think this circuit will work?

Answer (score 0):

You also can use 10 transistors, you connect the SPST switch to the base of each transistor. Than each collector/emitter pair takes care of the current to be flow for each channel. Most transistors will be able to manage 50 mA easily.

There are ICs too for this, but probably not with 10 lines but (max) 8, so you need 2 ICs (transistors might be easier in this case).

Relays are overkill for just 50 mA each.

If the devices are all using the same voltage (or most of them), you can also run them in parallel possibly.

Read https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor about resistors.

Comment: As the commenters on this thread pointed out, we don't know the application. If this a digital bidirectional communication then transistors wouldn't work. Maybe a bidirectional CMOS tristate buffer package would work for that application, but it would pass CMOS logic signals, and probably a lot less than 50mA.

Comment: Apologies.  Clarifications I should have included originally:  8 individual data logic level lines (bi-directional), 1 ground, and one 5V, 50mA max power line.  With the flip of a single switch, I want to break all 10 individual connections.  I initially thought to use 10 transistors as Michel suggested, but as Duncan mentioned bi-directional wouldn't work.

Comment: @da40flyer - Welcome to the site :-) (a) I recommend you read the [tour] and [help] to learn more about the site and how to use it. (b) Especially relevant now, is that important facts need to be put **into the question** and not left sprinkled in comments. So please can you fix the question (and the title) since your update here explains that both the question & title are wrong (e.g. there are 8 data lines, not 10) and also add the details requested in the comments under the question. (c) Also list any solutions you have already considered, but have decided won't work for you and why. Thanks.

Comment: @DuncanC Yes indeed, I was not thinking about a bidirection but serial could indeed be both sides.

Comment: @da40flyer Maybe you can indeed improve your question so we don't have to assume wrong things (like me).